Tailwind - Apply Justify-Between if multiple children else Justify-End
I have a Vuejs component with a flex div containing a slot. As I do not know how many elements will be in the slot, I would like the content to be 'justify-between' if there is more than 1 element, otherwise 'justify-end' (right aligned). Is that possible using just CSS in TailwindCss?
  <div class="flex justify-between gap-2 select-none" >
    <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-slate-400">justify-between</div>
    <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-slate-400">if 2+ divs</div>
    <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-red-400">justify-end if 1 div</div>
  </div>



Using Tailwind 3.4.4+, you can put conditional arbitrary selectors on the parent flex div using the :has() and :not() variants with the :only-child selector. It would be great to see a more streamlined way to do this but it works.


 <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="border border-red-500 m-5 p-5"> 

  <div class="flex justify-between [&:has(:only-child)]:justify-end gap-2 select-none" >
    <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-slate-400">justify-between</div>
    <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-slate-400">if 2+ divs</div>
    <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-red-400">justify-end if 1 div</div>
  </div>
 
</div>




WillC's answer requires some modify since :has(:only-child) will be applied if there is a nested child element that is the only child. (As shown in the third example below.) It can also be simplified since has already means &:has.
Use justify-between has-[>:only-child]:justify-end instead.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex justify-between has-[>:only-child]:justify-end gap-2 select-none">
  <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-red-400">justify-end if 1 div</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="flex justify-between has-[>:only-child]:justify-end gap-2 select-none">
  <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-slate-400">justify-between</div>
  <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-slate-400">if 2+ divs</div>
  <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-red-400">justify-end if 1 div</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="flex justify-between has-[>:only-child]:justify-end gap-2 select-none">
  <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-slate-400">Should be space between</div>
  <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-slate-400">
    <div>Nested only child</div>
  </div>
</div>



As a side note, you can also using auto margining to acheive the same result using justify-between only:*:ml-auto for a negligible slightly smaller file size. Choose which ever you think is more readable.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex justify-between only:*:ml-auto gap-2 select-none">
  <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-red-400">justify-end if 1 div</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="flex justify-between only:*:ml-auto gap-2 select-none">
  <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-slate-400">justify-between</div>
  <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-slate-400">if 2+ divs</div>
  <div class="px-5 py-3 font-extrabold bg-red-400">justify-end if 1 div</div>
</div>




Good to know about 'has-[>:only-child]:justify-end'.

Right! I can never get used to reading complex Tailwind classes though. So any TW classes that are longer than this I usually just use custom classes and @layers. IMO for more complex ones native css combinators are way easier to read.
